# insert data into table using the today() function

Tags: sas

I have a silly question...
for some reason I just can't get it work...

I want to insert a row into an empty table using the today(function).

This is what I do:

```
    insert into gal_risk_factor (RISK_FACTOR_ID, VALID_FROM_DTTM,
    RISK_FACTOR_NM, EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM, EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM)
    values ("1",today(),
    "GGG", 
    "01JAN1901:00:00:00"dt, "01JAN2999:00:00:00"dt
    )
```

This is the error I get:

```
                   today(),
                    _____
                    22
                    202
    ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a           numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
          a missing value, ), +, ',', -, MISSING, NULL, USER.  

    ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

What am I missing here...?

Thank you in advance,
Gal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the VALUES list cannot contain function, only constants.

Try creating a macro var and use it:

```
%let today=%sysfunc(today());
insert into gal_risk_factor (RISK_FACTOR_ID, VALID_FROM_DTTM,
    RISK_FACTOR_NM, EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM, EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM)
    values ("1", &today,
    "GGG", 
    "01JAN1901:00:00:00"dt, "01JAN2999:00:00:00"dt
    )
```

Edit:
In case VALID_FROM_DTTM is meant to store datetime values use a constant like this:

```
%let today_dttm=%sysfunc(dhms(%sysfunc(today()), 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Thank you, vasja. Works like a charm. Problem is, I get 01Jan60:05:26:36 as today's date... no idea where do I need to use the FORMAT option... suggestions?

Comment: See the EDIT of my answer.